# How can i equal a int to a int64_t with out getting the conversion loses integer precision warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, game-center, int64

I am getting the implicit conversion loses interger precision warning and need help finding a solution. I have seen similar problems but have not found a solution for my problem yet. This are the integers that are declared...

```
@property (nonatomic) int64_t score;
NSInteger highscorenumber;
```

this is whats in my .m file when game over function is called...

```
    if (score > highscorenumber) {
    highscorenumber = score;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highscorenumber forKey:@"highscoresaved"];
    [self clapsound];
}
else{
    highscore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score: %li",(long)highscorenumber];
}
```

the warning come up in this part

```
        highscorenumber = score;
```

if i change the highscorenumber to a int64_t the warning comes up here...

```
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highscorenumber forKey:@"highscoresaved"];
```

The reason i am using int64_t for score is to use GameKit (GameCenter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSInteger and long are always pointer-sized. That means they're 32-bits on 32-bit systems, and 64 bits on 64-bit systems.

Under mac os uint64_t defined as

```
typedef unsigned long long   uint64_t;
```

So, i recommend you to change highscorenumber to NSUInteger and save it to NSUserDefaults as

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@(highscorenumber) forKey:@"highscoresaved"];
```

**EDIT:**

Getting value back:

```
NSNumber *highscorenumber = (NSNumber*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"highscoresaved"];
```

Comment: ok, and when i want to load it back would i do it like this.     highscorenumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highscoresaved"];

Comment: no, you should cast it to NSNumber after valueForKey: selector. Remember - you should use exactly the same method to set and get data: for example, if you set data throw 'setValue', you must get it like 'valueForKey', if you set throw 'setInteger: forKey' call 'integerForKey:'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
highscorenumber = @(score);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
highscorenumber = [score integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `NSInteger` for storing `highscorenumber`?
If you want it to be compatible with GameKit it should be 64-bit,
you need to use int64_t for your highscore property

```
int64_t highscorenumber;
```